# VS 2017 Preview Python Package Import Issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-2017, cntk

I have an custom conda environment set up in VS2017 Preview for some ML packages I want to run against each other in a single env (CNTK, Tensorflow, ... ect). When importing the modules from a Interactive Window in VS there is no problem, but when I try to attach a debugger and run I seem to get import errors. Is there some custom search path I need to add or some command to "activate" the conda env within my script aside from setting it as the active environment in my solution?

[image: [Loading While Attached to Debugger]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Y0C.jpg)

[image]
**Edit**: Figured out my issue, I had to set the solution working directory to the location of my virtual env, oops ><, anyway that seems to clear up import errors

Comment: You shouldn't edit your original post with the answer. If you've come up with a solution, add it down below so that others can see what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my issue, I had to set the solution working directory to the location of my virtual env, oops ><, anyway that seems to clear up import errors